# Starting Node.js Thread Pool for Parallelism

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, mongodb, parallel-processing

Yes hello.  I recently came to learn that Node.js is single-threaded.  I would like to use my application faster (MongoDB/Express app) so I have written the following script (I want it to use 8 processors)

```
#!/bin/bash
node app.js &
node app.js &
node app.js &
node app.js &
node app.js &
node app.js &
node app.js &
node app.js &
```

When I try to run the script, I get many errors about ports being used, but I know that TCP allows for 65536 ports and it should only try to use 8.  Do I need to update my Node.js to a new version?

I am running on Amazon Linux.

Thank you.

Comment: You've likely configured it to always use the same port.

Comment: Use the node.js `cluster` module to fire up N processes to all handle requests on the same port.  Note: If your app is written with proper async I/O and you are database bound (e.g. the database is what is restricting your response times), then it may not help much to fire up more processes.  Node.js may be single threaded, but your database is likely it's own process and node.js can handle many requests at once with proper async I/O coding.

Answer (score 4):

Each of the processes is trying to listen on the same port. You should use Node's built-in cluster module to handle creating the child processes for you, as it will allow a single port to be shared by all the children automatically.